# PowerPoint "opens" as minimized on taskbar

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a user that is unable to open a particular powerpoint file from one of our network shares (it will launch but only on the taskbar). Other powerpoints from this location open just fine from the share. If we drag it to his local machine it also opens just fine.

Tried running a repair on his office install and powerpoint file itself. It seems like it might something with the file in particular, yet a local copy of it will open just fine. I thought it might be set to open in a different off-screen location, yet I can't seem to locate the window (tried changing resolution to the lowest).

I'm thinking of updating his graphics driver next? He isn't docked in or anything. When I move the working copy back to the network share the same result occurs where it will launch as minimized on the taskbar.

This is Office 2016 Powerpoint on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution found: Ran repair on office installation and rebooted. Later in the day I tried opening in protected mode from powerpoint application > Open > Open in protected view. This opened the file successfully, I then enabled editing. After that we were able to launch directly from the network share with no issues. Unclear exactly what was causing this but issue is now resolved (likely something with how application was opening and where it gets displayed on the screen).

Comment: Thanks for your kind sharing. Considering the issue is mainly related to specific file from network shares, it may be caused by file validation failure. when you use Open in protected view, it will start up a new process and open a new window in Protected View. It may help correct the file validation failure.